# How to reconcile Rama's Vishwaroopa, Upanishads and Krishna saying he is Rama only among warriors?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, ramayana, rama, upanishads

Lord Rama is often known as the supreme being according to Vaishnavism. This is evidenced by many scriptural refereces:

> Brahma in *Valmiki Ramayana 6.117.31-32* calls **Rama the first/primeval and eternal lord**

> Shiva says "When that **Supreme being of Vedas** born as son of Dasratha (Śrī Rām) in Ayodhya, that time all Vedas manifested themselves through the mouth of sage Valmiki..... directly as Ramayana. Therefore .... there is no doubt that Sri **Ramayana is the Vedas** itself" *[(Mangalacharan of Valmiki Ramayana; & Agastya samhita)](http://lordrama.org/pramana.html)*

> **Rama is Para-Brahma and supreme austerity**, and Rama is the Supreme Essence and Brahma Taraka. [(Rama Rahasya Upanishad 1.6)](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/vedicsection/upanishads/ramarahasya.asp)

> रमन्ते योगिनोऽनन्ते नित्यानन्दे चिदात्मनि । इति रामपदेनासौ परंब्रह्माभिधियते ।।
> *(- श्रीरामपूर्वतापनीय उपनिषद १।६ )* or The Parabrahman which is infinite, immeasurable, pure consciousness, eternal and forever blissful, on which Yogis devote themselves and meditate continuously; **that Parabrahman itself is denoted by word ‘Rāma’** directly in Abhidhaa Vritti. *([Shri Rama-PurvaTapnIya Upanishada](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/vedicsection/upanishads/ramatapaniya.asp))*

> राम त्वं परमात्मसि सच्चिदानन्दविग्रहः॥ इदानीं त्वां रघुश्रेष्ठ प्रणमामि मुहुर्मुहुः। (शुक्लयजुर्वेदीय मुक्तिकोपनिषद् 1/4,5क)
> **“O' Śrī Rāma! You are the Supreme Being (Paramatma)**, The Parambrahman, of the nature Sat, Chit and Ananda! I pay my obeisance in your lotus feet again and again.”
> ([Muktika Upanishada 1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/muktika-upanishad-of-shukla-yajurveda/d/doc216984.html))

His Vishwaroopa is discussed in Adbudh Ramayan, Sri Ramcharitmanas 1.202.1,2 and even in the Mahabharata:

> “Behold me now in my native form: I give thee sight.' Then **Rama of Bhrigu's race beheld in the body of Dasaratha's son** the Adityas with the Vasus, the Rudras, the Sadhyas with the Marutas, the Pitris, Hutasana, the stellar constellations and the planets, the Gandharvas, the Rakshasas, the Yakshas, the Rivers, the tirthas, those eternal Rishis identified with Brahma and called the Valkhilyas, the celestial Rishis, the Seas and Mountains, the Vedas with the Upanishads and Vashats and the sacrifices, the Samans in their living form, the Science of weapons, O Bharata, and the Clouds with rain and lightning, O Yudhishthira! And the illustrious Vishnu then shot that shaft.” *([Mahabharata, Vanaparva, Tirthyatra Parva, section XCIX](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03099.htm))*

[image]

**But Bhagavad Gita 11.47 says his Vishwaroop is being shown for first time ever !!** And then we see in Bhagavad Gita that Krishna says that he is only Rama among warriors and Rama is mentioned along with lion, Garuda, Prahlada, wind and Ganges!! Like he is almost **degrading Rama** to just a warrior and a small portion of himself:

> **पवनः पवतामस्मि रामः शस्त्रभृतामहम्। ।10.31। or Among the purifiers (or the speeders) I am the wind; RAMA AMONG THE WARRIORS AM I**

How can Krishna's words and everything else be reconciled? [Even in Krishna Upanishad Rama tells that he will reincarnate as Krishna.](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/vedicsection/upanishads/krishna.asp)

Can these 2 different parts **(Vishwaroop & warrior part)** be considered interpolations in Bhagavad Gita? *EDIT - It seems there is an interpolation in B Gita 10.37 (based on answer) because it says Vrishinam in one version and Yadavam in another!*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126404/discussion-on-question-by-r-kaushik-how-to-reconcile-ramas-vishwaroopa-upanis).

Answer (score 5):

> And then we see in Bhagavad Gita that Krishna says that he is only Rama among warriors and Rama is mentioned along with lion, Garuda, Prahlada, wind and Ganges!! Like he is almost degrading Rama to just a warrior and a small portion of himself

This is not degradation. In this chapter, Krishna is giving Brahman's divine manifestations (दिव्य विभूतियाँ). In [BG 10.37](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=37&etpurohit=1&setgb=1&etssa=1), he gives his own name too:

> वृष्णीनां वासुदेवोऽस्मि...
>
> 10.37 Vrsninam, of the Vrsnis, [Here Ast. adds yadavanam, of the Yadavas.-Tr.] I am Vasudeva- I who am this person, your friend. ~ *English Translation Of Sri Shankaracharya's Sanskrit Commentary By Swami Gambirananda*
>
> 10.37. Of the Vrsnis (the members of the Vrsni clan), I am the son of Vasudeva; ~ *English Translation By By Dr. S. Sankaranarayan*
>
> 10.37 I am Shri Krishna among the Vrishni-clan ~ *English Translation by Shri Purohit Swami*

So by this shloka, should one conclude that Krishna is just a Yadava / Vrishni like you concluded Rama is just a warrior? No, this is not the right interpretation. To interpret correctly, one has to read the entire chapter at least.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126334/discussion-on-answer-by-yds-how-to-reconcile-ramas-vishwaroopa-upanishads-and).